# Comparación de valores que pueden ser NaN en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Es segura una comparación de un valor entero con un dato NaN en Javascript? Por ejemplo, haciendo uso de jQuery:

```
var notaValidaEliminatoria = grupoEliminatorio.notaEliminatoriaValida();
var notaEliminatoria = parseInt(componenteEliminatorio.grupoEliminatorio.val());
if(notaValidaEliminatoria > notaEliminatoria) {
    ...
}
```

La variable `notaEliminatoria` puede contener `NaN` si el valor de `componenteEliminatorio.grupoEliminatorio.val()` (un campo en un formulario) es vacío. ¿Ocurrirá siempre que cualquier valor entero es menor o igual a `NaN` o estoy forzado a detectar con `isNaN()` si es o no un número y si lo es realizar la comparación?

Comment: _cualquier valor entero es menor o igual a NaN_ .. ¿como puede ser menor o igual, si **no es un numero**? manzanas y naranjas :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta parte del código:

```
if(notaValidaEliminatoria > notaEliminatoria) {
```

Si cualquiera de las dos variables (o las dos) es NaN el reasultado siempre será `false`, lo cual probablemente no es el comportamiento esperado.

Primero deberías validar con `isNaN()` la variable que podría ser NaN, (en este caso al parecer `notaEliminatoria` debido al `parseInt()`) y ya tu decide que hacer al respecto.

Por ejemplo:

```
var notaValidaEliminatoria = grupoEliminatorio.notaEliminatoriaValida();
var notaEliminatoria = parseInt(componenteEliminatorio.grupoEliminatorio.val());

if (isNaN(notaEliminatoria)) {
    throw "notaEliminatoria es inválida";
}

if(notaValidaEliminatoria > notaEliminatoria) {
    ...
}
```

O en lugar del `throw` hacer un `return` del método o lo que sea apropiado en tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso especifico, si realizas el `parseInt()`:

```
var notaEliminatoria = parseInt(componenteEliminatorio.grupoEliminatorio.val());
    if(notaValidaEliminatoria > notaEliminatoria) {
        ...
    }
```

creo que no es necesario, ya que `notaEliminatoria` tendría siempre un valor entero, si es que no ocurre antes un error en la conversión.

Yo optaría por validar `componenteEliminatorio.grupoEliminatorio.val()` antes de realizar el `parserInt()`.

```
if (isNaN(componenteEliminatorio.grupoEliminatorio.val())) {
  notaEliminatoria = 0; //No númerico, define un valor default.
}else{
   notaEliminatoria = parseInt(componenteEliminatorio.grupoEliminatorio.val());
}
```

Comment: si `componenteEliminatorio.grupoEliminatorio.val()` retorna un string con cualquier valor no numérico, `isNaN()` devolverà `false` sin embargo al parsearlo como Int devolverá `NaN` y estamos en el mismo problema que antes

Comment: tienes razón Carlos, yo proponía un valor default ( 0 ) en caso de que fuera NaN.